# resetForm() on Formik doesn't clear all fields

Tags: reactjs, formik

I'm building a form using ReactJS + Formik. Currently when I submit a form and use resetForm() to clean all inputs, it only works on a few of them. I have a JSON Schema like this:

```
 initialValues={{
        email: '',
        name: '',
        cpf: '',
        telephone: '',
        addresses: [
          {
            cep: '',
            state: 'AC',
            city: '',
            neighborhood: '',
            address: '',
            number: '',
            complement: '',
            type: 0,
            main: true
          }
        ]
      }}
```

There's this nested objected, all of the addresses objects do not reset when I'm submitting. I tried using a work around with `setFieldValue('cep', '')` but then I become unable to type on the field, because it sets it to an empty state all the time.

EDIT:

```
return (
    <div className="container-add">
      <div className="content-add">
        {console.log('eita formik')}
        <Link to="/list">
          <button className="btn-voltar">Voltar</button>
        </Link>
        <h2 className="add-title-main">Editar Cliente</h2>
        <Formik
          enableReinitialize
          initialValues={{
            email: '',
            name: '',
            cpf: '',
            telephone: ''
            addresses: [
              {
                cep: '',
                state: '',
                city: '',
                neighborhood: '',
                address: '',
                number: '',
                complement: '',
                type: 0,
                main: true
              }
            ]
          }}
          onSubmit={async (
            values,
            { resetForm, props, setSubmitting, setFieldValue }
          ) => {
            const validarCpf = require('validar-cpf');
            const cpfValido = validarCpf(values.cpf);
            //Valida o CPF
            if (!cpfValido) {
              Swal.fire('Oops...', 'O CPF informado é inválido!', 'error');
            } else {
              alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
              try {
                await api.post('/users', values);
                Swal.fire('Sucesso!', 'Cliente cadastrado!', 'success');
                resetForm();
                setFieldValue('cep', '');
                setFieldValue('city', '');
                setFieldValue('neighborhood', '');
                setFieldValue('address', '');
                setFieldValue('number', '');
                setFieldValue('complement', '');
              } catch (error) {
                Swal.fire('Oops...', error.response.data.error, 'error');
                setSubmitting(false);
              }
            }
          }}
          validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
            name: Yup.string()
              .required('Campo Obrigatório')
              .min(8, 'Digite o nome completo'),
            cpf: Yup.string()
              .required('Campo Obrigatório')
              .min(14, 'Digite o CPF completo'),
            email: Yup.string()
              .email('E-mail inválido')
              .required('Campo Obrigatório'),
            telephone: Yup.string()
              .required('Campo Obrigatório')
              .min(10, 'Digite um telefone válido'),
            addresses: Yup.array().of(
              Yup.object().shape({
                cep: Yup.string()
                  .required('Campo Obrigatório')
                  .min(8, 'Digite o CEP completo'),
                city: Yup.string()
                  .required('Campo Obrigatório')
                  .min(2, 'Digite o nome completo da cidade'),
                neighborhood: Yup.string()
                  .required('Campo Obrigatório')
                  .min(2, 'Digite o nome completo do bairro'),
                address: Yup.string()
                  .required('Campo Obrigatório')
                  .min(2, 'Digite o endereço completo'),
                number: Yup.string().required('Campo Obrigatório')
              })
            )
          })}
        >
          {props => {
            const {
              values,
              touched,
              errors,
              isSubmitting,
              handleChange,
              handleBlur,
              handleSubmit,
              setFieldValue
            } = props;
            return (
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                {/* NOME */}
                <h2 className="add-title">Dados do Cliente</h2>
                <label htmlFor="name" style={{ display: 'block' }}>
                  Nome
                </label>
                <input
                  id="name"
                  placeholder=""
                  type="text"
                  value={values.name}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  className={
                    errors.name && touched.name
                      ? 'text-input error'
                      : 'text-input'
                  }
                />
                {errors.name && touched.name && (
                  <div className="input-feedback">{errors.name}</div>
                )}
                {/* CPF */}
                <label htmlFor="cpf" style={{ display: 'block' }}>
                  CPF
                </label>
                <MaskedInput
                  mask={[
                    /[0-9]/,
                    /\d/,
                    /\d/,
                    '.',
                    /\d/,
                    /\d/,
                    /\d/,
                    '.',
                    /\d/,
                    /\d/,
                    /\d/,
                    '-',
                    /\d/,
                    /\d/
                  ]}
                  id="cpf"
                  guide={false}
                  placeholder=""
                  type="text"
                  value={values.cpf}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  className={
                    errors.cpf && touched.cpf
                      ? 'text-input error'
                      : 'text-input'
                  }
                />
                {errors.cpf && touched.cpf && (
                  <div className="input-feedback">{errors.cpf}</div>
                )}

                {/* EMAIL */}
                <label htmlFor="email" style={{ display: 'block' }}>
                  Email
                </label>
                <input
                  id="email"
                  placeholder=""
                  type="text"
                  value={values.email}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  className={
                    errors.email && touched.email
                      ? 'text-input error'
                      : 'text-input'
                  }
                />
                {errors.email && touched.email && (
                  <div className="input-feedback">{errors.email}</div>
                )}

                {/* TELEFONE */}
                <label htmlFor="telephone" style={{ display: 'block' }}>
                  Telefone
                </label>
                <MaskedInput
                  mask={[
                    '(',
                    /[0-9]/,
                    /\d/,
                    ')',
                    ' ',
                    /\d/,
                    /\d/,
                    /\d/,
                    /\d/,
                    /\d/,
                    '-',
                    /\d/,
                    /\d/,
                    /\d/,
                    /\d/
                  ]}
                  id="telephone"
                  placeholder=""
                  type="text"
                  guide={false}
                  value={values.telephone}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  className={
                    errors.telephone && touched.telephone
                      ? 'text-input error'
                      : 'text-input'
                  }
                />
                {errors.telephone && touched.telephone && (
                  <div className="input-feedback">{errors.telephone}</div>
                )}
                <hr className="division"></hr>

                <h2 className="add-subtitle">Endereço Principal</h2>

                {/* CEP */}
                <label htmlFor="cep" style={{ display: 'block' }}>
                  CEP
                </label>
                <MaskedInput
                  mask={[/[0-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]}
                  guide={false}
                  id="cep"
                  placeholder=""
                  type="text"
                  name="addresses[0].cep"
                  value={values.cep}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  className={
                    getIn(errors, 'addresses[0].cep') &&
                    getIn(touched, 'addresses[0].cep')
                      ? 'text-input error'
                      : 'text-input'
                  }
                />
                <ErrorMessage
                  component="div"
                  name="addresses[0].cep"
                  className="input-feedback"
                />

                {/* Estado */}
                <label htmlFor="state" style={{ display: 'block' }}>
                  Estado
                </label>
                <select
                  id="state"
                  placeholder=""
                  name="addresses[0].state"
                  value={values.state}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  className={
                    getIn(errors, 'addresses[0].state') &&
                    getIn(touched, 'addresses[0].state')
                      ? 'text-input error'
                      : 'text-input'
                  }
                >
                  <option value="AC">Acre</option>
                  <option value="AL">Alagoas</option>
                  <option value="AP">Amapá</option>
                  <option value="AM">Amazonas</option>
                  <option value="BA">Bahia</option>
                  <option value="CE">Ceará</option>
                  <option value="DF">Distrito Federal</option>
                  <option value="ES">Espírito Santo</option>
                  <option value="GO">Goiás</option>
                  <option value="MA">Maranhão</option>
                  <option value="MT">Mato Grosso</option>
                  <option value="MS">Mato Grosso do Sul</option>
                  <option value="MG">Minas Gerais</option>
                  <option value="PA">Pará</option>
                  <option value="PB">Paraíba</option>
                  <option value="PR">Paraná</option>
                  <option value="PE">Pernambuco</option>
                  <option value="PI">Piauí</option>
                  <option value="RJ">Rio de Janeiro</option>
                  <option value="RN">Rio Grande do Norte</option>
                  <option value="RS">Rio Grande do Sul</option>
                  <option value="RO">Rondônia</option>
                  <option value="RR">Roraima</option>
                  <option value="SC">Santa Catarina</option>
                  <option value="SP">São Paulo</option>
                  <option value="SE">Sergipe</option>
                  <option value="TO">Tocantins</option>
                </select>
                <ErrorMessage
                  component="div"
                  name="addresses[0].state"
                  className="input-feedback"
                />

                {/* Cidade */}
                <label htmlFor="city" style={{ display: 'block' }}>
                  Cidade
                </label>
                <input
                  id="city"
                  placeholder=""
                  type="text"
                  name="addresses[0].city"
                  value={values.city}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  className={
                    getIn(errors, 'addresses[0].city') &&
                    getIn(touched, 'addresses[0].city')
                      ? 'text-input error'
                      : 'text-input'
                  }
                />
                <ErrorMessage
                  component="div"
                  name="addresses[0].city"
                  className="input-feedback"
                />

                {/* Bairro */}
                <label htmlFor="neighborhood" style={{ display: 'block' }}>
                  Bairro
                </label>
                <input
                  id="neighborhood"
                  placeholder=""
                  type="text"
                  name="addresses[0].neighborhood"
                  value={values.neighborhood}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  className={
                    getIn(errors, 'addresses[0].neighborhood') &&
                    getIn(touched, 'addresses[0].neighborhood')
                      ? 'text-input error'
                      : 'text-input'
                  }
                />
                <ErrorMessage
                  component="div"
                  name="addresses[0].neighborhood"
                  className="input-feedback"
                />

                {/* Endereço */}
                <label htmlFor="address" style={{ display: 'block' }}>
                  Endereço
                </label>
                <input
                  id="address"
                  placeholder=""
                  type="text"
                  name="addresses[0].address"
                  value={values.address}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  className={
                    getIn(errors, 'addresses[0].address') &&
                    getIn(touched, 'addresses[0].address')
                      ? 'text-input error'
                      : 'text-input'
                  }
                />
                <ErrorMessage
                  component="div"
                  name="addresses[0].address"
                  className="input-feedback"
                />

                {/* Número */}
                <label htmlFor="number" style={{ display: 'block' }}>
                  Número
                </label>
                <input
                  id="number"
                  placeholder=""
                  type="text"
                  name="addresses[0].number"
                  value={values.number}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  className={
                    getIn(errors, 'addresses[0].number') &&
                    getIn(touched, 'addresses[0].number')
                      ? 'text-input error'
                      : 'text-input'
                  }
                />
                <ErrorMessage
                  component="div"
                  name="addresses[0].number"
                  className="input-feedback"
                />

                {/* Complemento */}
                <label htmlFor="complement" style={{ display: 'block' }}>
                  Complemento
                </label>
                <input
                  id="complement"
                  placeholder=""
                  type="text"
                  name="addresses[0].complement"
                  value={values.complement}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  className={
                    getIn(errors, 'addresses[0].complement') &&
                    getIn(touched, 'addresses[0].complement')
                      ? 'text-input error'
                      : 'text-input'
                  }
                />
                <ErrorMessage
                  component="div"
                  name="addresses[0].complement"
                  className="input-feedback"
                />

                {/* Tipo */}
                <label htmlFor="type" style={{ display: 'block' }}>
                  Tipo do Endereço
                </label>
                <div className="radio">
                  <label name="" className="radio-label">
                    <Field
                      type="radio"
                      name="addresses[0].type"
                      value="0"
                      checked={values.addresses[0].type === '0'}
                      onChange={() => setFieldValue('addresses[0].type', '0')}
                    />
                    Comercial
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div className="radio">
                  <label className="radio-label">
                    <input
                      type="radio"
                      name="addresses[0].type"
                      value="1"
                      checked={values.addresses[0].type === '1'}
                      onChange={() => setFieldValue('addresses[0].type', '1')}
                    />
                    Residencial
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div className="radio">
                  <label className="radio-label">
                    <input
                      type="radio"
                      value="2"
                      checked={values.addresses[0].type === '2'}
                      onChange={() => setFieldValue('addresses[0].type', '2')}
                    />
                    Rural
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div className="radio">
                  <label className="radio-label">
                    <input
                      type="radio"
                      name="addresses[0].type"
                      value="3"
                      checked={values.addresses[0].type === '3'}
                      onChange={() => setFieldValue('addresses[0].type', '3')}
                    />
                    Casa de Praia
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div className="end-secundario"></div>

                <button type="" disabled={isSubmitting}>
                  +
                </button>

                <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
                  Cadastrar
                </button>
              </form>
            );
          }}
        </Formik>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing the code of your form?

Comment: Added the code for the form

Comment: I think you don't need `enableReinitialize`. And which fields exactly are not being cleared after you call `resetForm`?

Comment: all the fields inside addresses:[ ] are not cleared. I tried without, it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
<MaskedInput
  ...
  name="addresses[0].cep"
  value={values.cep}
  onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

value should be `values.addressess[0].cep` instead of `values.cep`

Comment: Can you console.log values, and try to use getIn(values, ‘addresses[0].cep’)